# Create daily portfolio snapshot based on portfolio at specific date and trades thereafter

Tags: python

I'm trying to build a stock portfolio tracker in Python that takes as input two tables:

- Portfolio at Start Date
- Trades after the Start Date

And creates a table with the value of my portfolio every day. My objective is to be able to track my portfolio over time to see which stocks are impacting the increase or decrease every day.

Any ideas?

Here is how my data looks like.

**Portfolio Value**

```
    Symbol  Quantity    Close Price Currency
30  NVDA    52          301.21      USD
29  NFLX    18          597.37      USD
33  QQQ     26          401.68      USD
26  KSS     88          49.58       USD
```

**Trades**

```
    Symbol  Currency    Date/Time               Quantity    Comm/Fee
226 KO      USD         2022-08-19, 10:43:28    20          -1
131 CLH     USD         2022-12-13, 09:30:17    2           0
181 IDV     USD         2022-12-12, 09:38:03    -86         -1.065204581
317 SPY     USD         2022-06-30, 09:55:25    -2          -0.017365842
241 MSFT    USD         2022-06-28, 14:41:32    -13         -1.078205152
212 JNJ     USD         2022-12-12, 12:04:16    7           -1
```

thanks!

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Comment: I tried to follow Step 3 in https://towardsdatascience.com/modeling-your-stock-portfolio-performance-with-python-fbba4ef2ef11 but I gave up because it seems to me either that their solution is too complex, or maybe that I myself don't see the complexity of this problem. In their case though they reconstruct the initial portfolio based on all the trades. In my case, I have the initial portfolio already.